# How to enter a value in a masked field in selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, visual-studio-code

**Guys I have the following problem:**
[Solution Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9jS1.png)

**What happens is that I need to enter a value in each of these fields using selenium, but the same s have a very similar identification, which you suggest to me in this case.
I'm using Python.**

Comment: Just use /input[1] an index based xpath or use //input from the parent div to get them all.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Can you remove the bold for the text... it's very aggressivbe! ;:)